# Relevance feedback in Apache Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, information-retrieval

I would like to implement [relevance feedback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevance_feedback) in [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). Solr already has a [More Like This](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis) feature: Given a *single* document, return a set of similar documents ranked by similarity to the single input document. Is it possible to configure Solr's More Like This feature to behave like More Like *Those*? In other words: Given a set of documents, return a list of documents similar to the input set (ranked by similarity).

According to the answer to [this question](http://qnalist.com/questions/651481/more-like-these-recommendation-system) turning Solr's More Like This into More Like Those can be done in the following way:

1. Take the url of the result set of the query returning the specified documents. For example, the url `http://solrServer:8983/solr/select?q=id:1%20id:2%20id:3` returns the response to the query `id:1 id:2 id:3` which is practically the concatenation of documents 1, 2, 3.
2. Put the above url (concatenation of the specified documents) in the `url.stream` GET parameter of the More Like This handler: `http://solrServer:8983/solr/mlt?mlt.fl=text&mlt.mintf=0&stream.url=http://solrServer:8983/solr/select%3Fq=id:1%20id:2%20id:3`. Now the More Like This handler treats the concatenation of documents 1, 2 and 3 as a single input document and returns a ranked set of documents similar to the concatenation.

This is a pretty bad implementation: Treating the set of input documents like one big document discriminates against short documents because short documents occupy a small portion of the entire big document.

Solr's More Like This feature is implemented by a variation of [The Rocchio Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocchio_algorithm): It takes the top 20 terms of the (single) input document (the terms with the highest TF-IDF values) and uses those terms as the modified query, boosted according to their TF-IDF. I am looking for a way to configure Solr's More Like This feature to take multiple documents as its input, extract the top n terms from each input document and query the index with those terms boosted according to their TF-IDF.

Is it possible to configure More Like This to behave that way? If not, what is the best way to implement relevance feedback in Solr?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to configure the MLT handler that way.

One way to do it would be to implement a custom [SearchComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchComponent) and register it to a (dedicated) [SearchHadler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler).

I've already done something similar and it is quite easy if you look a the [original implementation](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/solr/branches/branch-1.4/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/MoreLikeThisHandler.java) of MLT component.

The most difficult part is the synchronization of the results from different shard servers, but it can be skipped if you do not use shards.

I would also strongly recommend to use **your own** parameters in your implementation to prevent collisions with other components.